# How to prevent single lines from disappearing when cycle with TAB key?

Tags: org-mode

Sometimes my latex commands (with `#+LATEX:`) get buried within my org document. Can I disable the visibility cycle behavior for single lines?

A preferred behavior would be to leave non-indented lines always visible.

Comment: Would using occur help you? For example, `M-s` `o` `#+latex:` should all the `#+LATEX:` lines in buffer.

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I'm looking for